# Remember app selection in gnome3 search

Tags: linux, gnome3, launcher

[image]

Is there a way to tell gnome to remember app selection in the search?

1. Let's say I write `ter` and go and open "simple terminal".
2. When I search again for `ter`, simple terminal should be the first option.